# Different fonts in same math environment

Tags: fonts, math-mode, typewriter

I would like to display text like `0^3 1^5 ...` with the exponents (3 and 5 in the example, can be any number) written in usual math, but the bases (0 and 1) in typewriter font.

I tried various combinations of (inline) math, \verb and \texttt, but none looked right.

The result should look like this:

```
$
\text{\texttt{0}}^4
\text{\texttt{1}}^3
\text{\texttt{0}}
\text{\texttt{1}}^2
$
```

But this is quite cumbersome to type.

Comment: Do you want _all_ text in the base to be in tt and all text in the scripts to be as normal? If so you could abbreviate the markup a bit more than the given answer (although that might not be wise:-)

Comment: David: Yes, all bases.

Comment: So you want that in `$x=1$` also the “x” appears in typewriter style?

Comment: @egreg This does not appear in my use case, so either is fine with me :)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $
  \mathtt{0}^4
  \mathtt{1}^3
  \mathtt{0}
  \mathtt{1}^2
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is already much better (and I feel stupid for not knowing `mathtt`). I suppose this is as far as we can go?

Comment: @mafu As far as we can go! :)

Comment: @mafu there is always `\newcommand \z{\mathtt}` to reduce typing, and depending on the answer to the question in comments you may be able to get rid of `\z` as well:-)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\everymath{%
\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\the\fam}}%
\textfont0=\textfont\tmp\relax}
\begin{document}

This isn't supported latex syntax, but


$0^4 1^3 0 1^2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, what about `$x=1$`?

Comment: @egreg I asked in a comment in the question if all non script text to be in `\mathtt` and my understanding is that the answer is yes. See also the OP's self answer

Comment: I have no idea how, but this seems to work! What do you mean by 'not supported syntax'?

Comment: @mafu I mean if you reported a bug in latex with a document that does `\everymath{%
\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\the\fam}}%
\textfont0=\textfont\tmp\relax}` we'd probably tell you to go away unless you could reproduce the problem using commands found in the latex book, or the latex companion or anything else claiming to be about latex:-)

Comment: @mafu -- this uses tex primitives directly, not documented latex constructs.  `\textfont` means the font that is used for "baseline" text.  (the two sizes for sub/superscripts are `\scriptfont` and `\scriptscriptfont'.)  the `0` means that this is the basic roman font, which includes letters, digits and basic punctuation.  you really don't want to fiddle with these unless you really know what you're doing, and even then, you should check relevant code in the guts of all packages you're using to make sure you don't botch anything.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for the explanation. Amazing how much there is to learn!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve the normal math setup for formulas, the only way is to mark up the places where you want these special numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\DeclareSymbolFont{ttnumbers}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathtt}{ttnumbers}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathVersion{ttn}
\let\mv@ttn\mv@normal
\begingroup
\def\temp#1#2\@nil{\endgroup\def\mv@ttn{\mod@getanddefine@fonts#2}}%
\expandafter\temp\mv@ttn\@nil

\let\mod@getanddefine@fonts\getanddefine@fonts
\patchcmd\mod@getanddefine@fonts
  {\string #2}
  {OT1/cmtt/m/n}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ttn}[1]{\text{\mathversion{ttn}$#1$}}

\begin{document}
$a+b=\ttn{2^3\cdot3^5}-\log x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\ttn` can also be used in normal text.

Answer (score 1):

This compares what the OP had to my `\wackymode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\svcarat^
\catcode`^=\active
\def^#1{\ifmmode\svcarat#1\else\textsuperscript{\rmfamily#1}\fi}
\def\wackymode{\catcode`^=\active\ttfamily}
\catcode`^=7
\def\wackydone{\catcode`^=7}
\begin{document}
$
\text{\texttt{0}}^4
\text{\texttt{1}}^3
\text{\texttt{0}}
\text{\texttt{1}}^2
$

\wackymode
0^4%
1^3%
0%
1^2%
\wackydone
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\ifmmode` test in my active carat definition allows for a syntax like

```
\wackymode
\ensuremath{x^4}%
1^3%
0%
1^2%
\wackydone
```

to yield

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: If space between the symbols is acceptable, it is possible to write

```
\texttt{0$^4$ 1$^3$ 0 1$^2$}
```

[image]

Comment: (not sure if this is an intended use or a terrible hack)

Comment: the latter :- )